# Weird string manipulation issue

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a series of strings exactly the same length. I am trying to do these steps :

1. If the string is more than 25 characters, trim the extra.
2. If it's less than 25, fill it up with spaces.
3. Make sure that either way the strings are all 25 characters long.

Here is my code (or at least the relevant bit)

```
If Len(My.Settings.currOrder1) > 25 Then
    My.Settings.currOrder1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(My.Settings.currOrder1, 25)
Else
    My.Settings.currOrder1 = My.Settings.currOrder1 + "                           "
    My.Settings.currOrder1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(My.Settings.currOrder1, 25)
End If
```

which in my head should work. But if i run that code 3 times with a 6 character input, then 7, then 8, the output I get is this:

[image]

which is pretty obviously not shortening anything (the price is simply tacked on the end to show where the string ends). Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `My.Settings.currOrder1 = My.Settings.currOrder1.PadRight(25)` instead of adding and then trimming? Its a little more tidy. But still either way I think the issue is that the space takes up less room than an actual character

Comment: I agree with @ProGrammer ; `PadRight` is way simpler and you should try to use a monospaced font to have the same width for each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
Dim str As String = "Abc"
If str.Length < 25 Then
  str = str.PadRight(25 - str.Length, " "C)
Else
  str = str.Substring(0, 25)
End If
```

Comment: thanks a lot, such a simple and easy to implement answer. worked perfect. Only thing i needed to add, the resulting strings despite all being the same length, don't look the same size because of different sizes of different letters of the alphabet. took care of that by adding a tab character after the string before tagging on the price. since all the strings are now 25 characters long, the tab always comes out at the same location. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Usually, I don't upvote answers starting with "Try this", but here I made an exception. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general your VB6 approach should work also, but i'd use .NET:

```
Dim curOrder = My.Settings.currOrder1
If curOrder.Length > 25 Then
    My.Settings.currOrder1 = curOrder.Substring(0, 25)
ElseIf curOrder.Length < 25 Then
    My.Settings.currOrder1 = curOrder.PadRight(25, " "c)
End If
Debug.Assert( My.Settings.currOrder1.Length = 25 )
```